# How to play .ts files (video/MP2T media type) in Browser?

Tags: html, video, browser

I have one .m3u file that points to several .ts files (all in akamai).

Because we give to akamai a live stream, they convert it to these .ts files each of 10s. I see that the m3u files are easy to understand, but I can't find a browser based (flash, html5 or native plugin) player for these files.

If I give to vlc the link of the m3u file, vlc plays all the .ts files one after another as if it where only one big file. I want to use flash or something similar to be able to play in browser, the same way vlc can play those .m3u files.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are basically talking about Apple's HLS format.
You can use an html5 object in your web page. You can use http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/ flash plugin.  You can use jwplayer.  There are more choices (e.g. flowplayer).

Comment: I couldn't get it working using jwplayer :( Could you provide any example please?