# Video Streaming TS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to play .ts streaming video file in mobile devices through a web page link, kindly provide me any example of it. I have tried video source tag with type "application/x-mpegURL" but it is not working. Can we call the .ts video file in a HTML5 video tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play .ts files (video/MP2T media type) in Browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386510/how-to-play-ts-files-video-mp2t-media-type-in-browser)

Answer (score 2):

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386510/how-to-play-ts-files-video-mp2t-media-type-in-browser) (possible duplicate)

> You are basically talking about Apple's HLS format. You can use an
>   html5 object in your web page. You can use http://osmfhls.kutu.ru/
>   flash plugin. You can use jwplayer. There are more choices (e.g.
>   flowplayer).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the following jw player/flow player is having the premium pay account streaming features, can we get any example/code of instead of premium account options.

Comment: Are you using iis?

Comment: If the answer is yes so check your mime type