# web player to play http live stream having no format in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, web, streaming, live

I want to play HTTP live stream in all major browser at least in chrome.
My stream format coming from server is like:

```
http://ServerIp/priv/liveview.cgi?action=getVideoStream&publicCamId=1003&privateCamId=2
```

Everywhere I am seeing example of live stream, the URL contains some formats like `.m3u8`, `.mp4`, but for me Live URL is not containing any format.

Comment: I can assure you, the stream has a format, the URL doesn't need to, but the stream does ... what format is the stream data (mp4, webm, ogg, mjpeg ... etc)

Comment: Hi Jaromanda ,Thnx for you reply, actually I am getting only this type of stream .How I will know format of stream data from client side.

Comment: `I am getting only this type of stream` - really, "this" type ... can you be a little more explicit ... what type of stream are you getting ... you say it's **My stream format coming from server** - so, I would hope you would know what your server is sending ... mp4? webm? ogg? mjpeg? something else?

Comment: this type of stream means                                  http://ServerIp/priv/liveview.cgi?action=getVideoStream&publicCamId=1003&privateCamId=2    ..and it is MP2T type..

Comment: there's an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386510/how-to-play-ts-files-video-mp2t-media-type-in-browser) - not sure I agree with it, and since flash is dead (just nobody told Adobe, or they're not listening) it may not be the answer you want